# Correct my binarysearch index and out of range array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, helper

```
   #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int arr[], int b, int e, int number) {
 while (b <= e) {   //This loop will keep going until b (first elememt) is less than or equal to (last element)element
   int c = (b+e)/ 2;  

   if (arr[c] == number) { 
     return c;
   } else if (arr[c] <= number) { //if c less than number entered the loop will keep adding 1 to c and making it become b (first element)
     b = c + 1; //until the condition is no longer true
   } else {
     e = c - 1;
   }
 }

 return -1;
}

int main() {
   int size=0;
 int myarr[size];
 cin>> size;
 int num;
 int output;

 for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
   cin >> myarr[i];
 }

 cin >> num;

 output = binarySearch(myarr, 0, size, num);

 if (output == -1) {
   cout<<-1;
 } 
 else {
     cout << output;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I need some one to please correct my code so that binary search gives out the index of an element in the array and tell me the mistake I did because I am so confused right now

Comment: Binary search only works on a sorted array (in your case, ascending order). Are you inserting numbers in ascending order?

Comment: Note that `int size=0; int myarr[size];` is a VLA and those do not exist in standard C++. You also _first_ create the array with size `0` and _after_ you've created the array you ask the user how big the array should be.

Comment: Yes I am inserting the numbers in ascending order but I still can't seem to figure out the mistake

Comment: @Keith Do you see the mistake I pointed out?

Comment: When you fix the mistakenly empty array, you will still be indexing outside of it. Read some more about arrrays and their indexing in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes I saw it but I don't get how to fix it can you elaborate please

Comment: @Keith things in your program happens in the order you write them. If you create an array with size 0, then ask the user what size the array should have, how big do you think the array now is?

Answer (score 1):

Ted gave you the answer, but I'll spell it out further. Here's your code:

```
int size=0;       // Line 1
int myarr[size];  // Line 2
cin>> size;       // Line 3
```

Let's step through the code.

1. size = 0, myarray doesn't exist yet.
2. size still = 0, myarray is of length 0.
3. Size now whatever user entered (perhaps 5), but myarray is still of length 0.

You need to swap lines 2 and 3.

Now, to add to this -- variable length arrays are not standard C++. A lot of compilers will handle them, anyway, but it's considered a mistake to use it.

Most people will tell you to use:

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<int> myArray;
```

But that's more complexity. You can also do:

```
int * myArray = new int[size];
...
// When done:
delete myArray;
```

This is the proper way if you're not going to use std::vector<>.

Comment: thank u but I have a question if I enter array size 5 then enter the array for example 2 3 5 7 8 then I ask it to find 7 and it gives the answer 3 as index is that correct?

Comment: @Keith Yes, that's correct since arrays are zero-based, so you can use indices 0 - 4 if the array has the size 5. Index 0 = 2, index 1 = 3, index 2 = 5, index 3 = 7, index 4 = 8.